# Is there a solution to get notified using Twilio Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile, twilio, mobile-development, twilio-conversations

When we are not in the chat page, we need to get notified to understand a message has received. We use this library: twilio_chat_conversation: ^1.0.4
which is here: https://pub.dev/packages/twilio_chat_conversation

We can prepare whole chat functionality except notification, it is not working. Is there any solution to get notified? If there is, please contact with me? (If you think it is possible via channel, please could you explain it)